# How to set the external path to project directlory in redux-dev-tools extension options

Tags: reactjs, trace

I configured redux-dev-tools to use in my application.
When i tried to trace the actions dispatched, the file is opened in chrome source tab
But i want it to open it in vs code editor

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the extension page of redux-dev-tools
2. Click on Extension Options
3. Check the External Editor radio button
4. Type vscode
5. In the absolute path text field, keep '/'

[image]

Now while tracing, when you click on the code, it navigates directly to your configured editor